# How to describe json array in swagger?

Tags: swagger, lumen

Let's say i have an json like this :

```
{
    "cars": [
        { "name":"Ford", "models":[ "Fiesta", "Focus", "Mustang" ] },
        { "name":"BMW", "models":[ "320", "X3", "X5" ] },
        { "name":"Fiat", "models":[ "500", "Panda" ] }
    ]
}
```

how do i describe this in swagger (swagger-lume preferably) ?

Comment: You need to give a little more information. What are you doing with this array? Is it being returned from a GET request? Or is it being pushed into the service with a PUT? Swagger represents a complete definition, so you must define your service operations with your payload.

Comment: this json represents a request body, and is submited via post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To describe the "cars" object in swagger, it can be a handy trick to first of all model it in Json Schema:

```
{
   "type":"array",
   "items":{
      "type":"object",
      "required":[
         "name",
         "models"
      ],
      "properties":{
         "name":{
            "type":"string"
         },
         "models":{
            "type":"array",
            "items":{
               "type":"string"
            }
         }
      }
   }
}
```

> this json represents a request body, and is submited via post

You can then refer to that model when you define your HTTP operation:

```
{
   "swagger":"2.0",
   "info":{
      "description":"My Cars definition\n",
      "version":"1.0.0",
      "title":"Cars"
   },
   "paths":{
      "/postMyCars":{
         "post":{ // <-- HTTP post
            "summary":"Post my cars in!",
            "consumes":[
               "application/json"
            ],
            "parameters":[
               {
                  "name":"cars",
                  "in":"body", // <-- in request body
                  "description":"Cars to add to the system",
                  "required":true,
                  "schema":{ // <-- define your cars payload here
                     "type":"array",
                     "items":{
                        "type":"object",
                        "required":[
                           "name",
                           "items"
                        ],
                        "properties":{
                           "name":{
                              "type":"string"
                           },
                           "models":{
                              "type":"array",
                              "items":{
                                 "type":"string"
                              }
                           }
                        }
                     }
                  }
               }
            ],
            "responses":{
               "200":{
                  "description":"Cars OK"
               }
            }
         }
      }
   },
   "schemes":[
      "https",
      "http"
   ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, do you by any chance know how to model it using annotations in swagger-lume?

Comment: @VeljkoSirovljević unfortunately I don't. However the swagger I have posted is valid according to OpenAPI v2

Comment: (except for the inline comments.. which are not valid json)

Comment: Thank you Tom for your effort, i really appreciate your time. I am using swagger-lume and openAPI 3.0 , but still can make use of your help. Regards..